# O que é Bias em redes neurais?

Tags: inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais

Na minha aula de Inteligencia Artificial o professor abordou o assunto a respeito de redes neurais, que no caso, as redes neurais possuem as camadas, tais como: *entrada*, *oculta* e *saída* e os neurônios que compõe elas.

No entanto, ele citou o termo *bias* que me parece ser um neurônio, porém, este termo me deixou mais confuso em relação as redes neurais e eu gostaria de ter esta dúvida esclarecida.

## Dúvida

O que seria o Bias em relação a redes neurais?

Comment: É o plural do assistente do Bradesco :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simplificando, o Bias é uma entrada de valor "1" associada a um peso "b" em cada neurônio. Sua função é aumentar ou diminuir a entrada líquida, de forma a transladar a função de ativação no eixo.

Exemplo:

Para aproximar um conjunto de pontos a uma reta, usamos `y = a*x + b*1`, onde `a` e `b` são constantes. `x` eh uma entrada associada a um peso `a` e temos um peso `b` associado a entrada `1`.

Agora imagine que a função de ativação da rede é uma função linear.

Answer (score 4):

Na rede neural, algumas entradas são fornecidas a um neurônio artificial e, a cada entrada, um peso é associado. O peso aumenta a inclinação da função de ativação. Isso significa que o peso decide com que rapidez a função de ativação será ativada, enquanto a polarização é usada para atrasar o acionamento da função de ativação.

Para um neurônio típico, se as entradas forem `x1`, `x2` e `x3`, os pesos sinápticos a serem aplicados a eles serão denotados como `w1`, `w2` e `w3`.
O peso mostra a eficácia de uma entrada específica. Quanto maior o peso de entrada, mais ela influenciará na rede neural.

Por outro lado, Bias é como o intercepto adicionado em uma equação linear. É um parâmetro adicional na Rede Neural que é usado para ajustar a saída junto da soma ponderada das entradas para o neurônio. Ou seja, Bias é uma constante que ajuda o modelo de uma maneira que ele possa se adaptar melhor aos dados fornecidos.

Se não houver "bias", o modelo irá treinar sobre o ponto passando apenas pela origem, o que não está de acordo com o "mundo real". Também com a introdução do bias, o modelo se tornará mais flexível.

Por fim o bias ajuda a controlar o valor no qual a função de ativação será ativada.

Answer (score 1):

O modelo do neurônio matemático também pode incluir uma polarização ou bias de entrada. Esta variável é incluída ao somatório da função de ativação, com o intuito de aumentar o grau de liberdade desta função e, consequentemente, a capacidade de aproximação da rede. O valor do bias é ajustado da mesma forma que os pesos sinápticos. O bias possibilita que um neurônio apresente saída não nula ainda que todas as suas entradas sejam nulas. Por exemplo, caso não houvesse o bias e todas as entradas de um neurônio fossem nulas, então o valor da função de ativação seria nulo. Desta forma não poderíamos, por exemplo, fazer com o que o neurônio aprendesse a relação pertinente ao ”ou exclusivo” da lógica.

Fonte: http://deeplearningbook.com.br/o-neuronio-biologico-e-matematico/

Lê esse book ele é excelente!

Answer (score -1):

**Imagine o seguinte:**
Todo dia tu toma vai à padaria, compra algumas coisas pra comer e quando chega em casa tu toma café.
Porém **as vezes tu compra pão**, **as vezes compra bolo** ou outras coisa, **mas tu sempre compra café** pra tomar. **O bias é** isso, **o café**, é o valor constante que independente do outros valores esse valor sempre vai ter lá.
Ou seja, se teu café custa 3,50 sempre, as vezes as outras coisas que tu compra podem custar 10 reais, 7 reais, esses são os valores da entrada, mas tu sempre vai ter o teu bias custando 3,50 que é o seu café.